# How can I get a count of how many column names match a certain string in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a large BigQuery table that has 50-100 columns. I would like a query to count how many of those column names start with the string "a_" and how many start with "e_".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it is by using `bq` CLI tool:

`bq --format=prettyjson show dataset.table | grep '"name": "a_' | wc -l`

`bq --format=prettyjson show dataset.table | grep '"name": "e_' | wc -l`